# can we use Ignorecase with whitespace in mongorepository?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mongodb

Can any one suggest me , How to use "findbynameRegexIgnorecase" in mongorepository? I need to check (regex,Ignorecase) while finding the name itself. spring1.4.2.Release

```
public interface SampleAreaMongoRepository extends MongoRepository<SampleArea, String> {
SampleArea findByAreaRegexIgnoreCase(String area);}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can achieve this with SpringData mongo finder `@Query` annotation.

The query annotation was from `org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository` package

```
public interface MyMongoRepository extends MongoRepository<Users, String>{

    @Query(value = "{'name': {$regex : ?0, $options: 'i'}}")
    List<Users> findByAreaRegexIgnoreCase(String name);

}
```

`$regex : ?0` is the regex accepting input name as the parameter and `$options: 'i'` to ignore the case.

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Glad that it helped you.. :)